After merging meshes the vertex groups stopped moving with the bones
I decided to merge (ctrl+j) the body mesh with the head meshes, and although the vertex groups maintained the same name and vertices, the bone's no longer move the vertex groups.
Below you can see the object in the background before I merged, and in the foreground is after I merged with the armature highlighted to show that the mesh is not moving with the bone joints.


Hello could you please share your file?

Okay figured it out, there were two ways to fix it. One was going into the object properties -> Relations and setting the parent type to Armature, but this resulted in me having to rescale it so the easier way which I found on accident was to just select the body mesh last when selecting all the meshes to combine. This worked for me because the head was not animated and only the body was at this point.
